# shinyjs is not excecuting all actions inside observeEvent

Tags: shiny, shinyjs

I got an app that when you click on an `actionButton`, it should set an input to a certain value; and a click action should be made through `shinyjs`. However, only the first thing is happening; and I don't know how to make the second one happen. Or maybe it IS happening; but the data inside the `reactive` object is not getting updated.

Heres a minimal reprex:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  
  selectInput("selector", label = "Carb selector", choices = unique(mtcars$carb)),
  actionButton("generate", "OK!"),
  tableOutput("results"),
  actionButton("reset", "RESET"),
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$generate)
    isolate(
    mtcars %>% filter(carb == input$selector)
    )
  })
  
  output$results <- renderTable(data())

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    
    updateSelectInput(session, 
                      inputId = "selector",
                      label = "Carb selector updated",
                      choices = unique(mtcars$carb),
                      selected = 1)
    
    shinyjs::click("generate")#This does not seem trigger when you hit reset!
    
  })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why this behavior?

The architecture of your code is a bit questionable, but I will point out why it is behaving this way.

To understand this, let's first break the observer on `input$reset` into two:

```r
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    updateSelectInput(
      session,
      inputId = "selector",
      label = "Carb selector updated",
      choices = unique(mtcars$carb),
      selected = 1
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    shinyjs::click("generate") # This does not seem trigger when you hit reset!
  })
```

After that, let's have a look at the documentation of `updateSelectInput`:

> The input updater functions send a message to the client, telling it to change the settings of an input object. **The messages are collected and sent after all the observers (including outputs) have finished running.**

And there lies the answer. In other words, `shinyjs::click("generate")` will always execute before `update*Input()` effects kick in.

Basically, this is the flow:

```
1. User clicks 'reset' btn
2. That leads to a click on 'generate' btn
3. The `data()` reactive is re-evaluated
4. All observers are re-evaluated
5. `update*Input()` sends updates to the client
```

### Suggested solution

We can use number 4 above to our advantage by having a `reactiveVal()` that always has the most current value of 'selector' and is a step ahead of `update*Input()`.

I have made a few changes to your code to make it more explicit and straight to the point.

[image: Demo]

```r
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  selectInput("selector", label = "Carb selector", choices = unique(mtcars$carb)),
  actionButton("generate", "OK!"),
  tableOutput("results"),
  actionButton("reset", "RESET"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv_selector <- reactiveVal()
  observeEvent(input$selector, rv_selector(input$selector))

  data <- reactive({
    mtcars %>% filter(carb == rv_selector())
  }) |> bindEvent(input$generate)

  output$results <- renderTable(data())

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    updateSelectInput(
      session,
      inputId = "selector",
      label = "Carb selector updated",
      choices = unique(mtcars$carb),
      selected = 1
    )
    rv_selector(1) # Ensures server is updated before the client
    shinyjs::click("generate")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is triggering, but you don't see it in your dataset as you are not changing anything.  Try this

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),

  selectInput("selector", label = "Carb selector", choices = unique(mtcars$carb)),
  actionButton("generate", "OK!"),
  tableOutput("results"),
  actionButton("reset", "RESET"),

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data <- reactive({ 
    req(input$generate)
    # isolate(
      mtcars %>% filter(carb == input$selector) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(clickedtimes = input$generate)
    # )
  })

  output$results <- renderTable(data())

  observeEvent(input$reset, {

    updateSelectInput(session,
                      inputId = "selector",
                      label = "Carb selector updated",
                      choices = unique(mtcars$carb),
                      selected = 1)

    shinyjs::click("generate")#This does not seem trigger when you hit reset!

  })
  observe({print(input$generate)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Ok, but the `selectInput` changes to 1. I would like to see what should come next: the clicking of `input$generate` and therefore the filtered data by `carb == 1`

Comment: Comment out the `isolate` and it works.  Please try the updated code.